# Type-field example in "Programming in Scala" doesn't work when statically typed using superclass

Tags: scala

*Programming in Scala*, First Edition, chapter 20, found [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html), contains this code in Listings 20.9 & 20.10 (slightly modified so cows have names):

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

class Grass extends Food
class Cow(name: String) extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) { println(s"cow '${name}' eats ${food}") }
}

class Fish extends Food

val bessy: Animal = new Cow("bessy")

// Fails to compile, as expected
bessy eat (new Fish)
```

Ok, understood so far, because only `Grass` is suitable for `Cow`. But then I tried this:

```
// Also fails to compile!
bessy eat (new Grass)
```

The compiler error is:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : $file.memberType.Grass
 required: bessy.SuitableFood
  bessy eat (new Grass)
```

I was really confused why a `Cow` couldn't eat a `Grass` instance. Then I noticed the static type of `bessy` is `Animal` and decided to try making the static type `Cow`:

```
// Works
bessy.asInstanceOf[Cow] eat (new Grass)

// Also works
val cow_as_cow = new Cow("cow_as_cow")
cow_as_cow eat (new Grass)
```

Do type fields only work if the static type matches the class that contains it? If so, is the example in the book misleading?

Comment: `Animal` class doesn't have a fixed `SuitableFood` type, hence you can't make arbitrary animal eat grass. In order to fix it, `bessy` should be defined this way: `val bessy = new Cow("bessy")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given example isn't wrong, but it is misleading, because no `Animal` instantiated in that way (`val name: Animal = new Animal-subtype`) can `eat` any type of `Food`.

You'll notice that the next example code, with `lassie`, doesn't repeat that pattern.  I suspect it was corrected in later editions but I don't have one to verify that.

The compiler adheres to the ascripted type if that's what you tell it to do.

```
abstract class A {val a = 1}
class B extends A {val b = 2}
val x: B = new B  // a complete B
x.a  // 1
x.b  // 2
val y: A = new B  // a restricted "view" of B (only the A parts)
y.a  // 1
y.b  // won't compile
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my hunch. FYI the latest edition (Third Ed for Scala 2.12) still uses `Animal` as the static type for `bessy`.